# Should I index primary key column(s) in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, primary-key

I've recently stopped to think that Primary Keys are not indexes, they're a combination of Unique and Null constraints. And till now, I've never created index for PK columns. My question is if I should create index for PK columns if this column is going to be used in the WHERE part of many queries.

Comment: Primary keys _are_ indexed.

Comment: To see the index that backs the primary key constraint: 
select ui.*
from USER_CONSTRAINTS uc, USER_INDEXES ui
where uc.table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
and constraint_type = 'P'
and ui.TABLE_OWNER = uc.OWNER
and ui.TABLE_NAME = uc.TABLE_NAME
and ui.INDEX_NAME = uc.INDEX_NAME;

Comment: Oracle Database enforces a UNIQUE key or PRIMARY KEY integrity constraint on a table by creating a unique index on the unique key or primary key. This index is automatically created by the database when the constraint is enabled.

Comment: No action is required by you when you issue the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement to create the index, but you can optionally specify a USING INDEX clause to exercise control over its creation. This includes both when a constraint is defined and enabled, and when a defined but disabled constraint is enabled.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Oracle will create an index for you, or can use an existing one. Whether a unique or non-unique index is used is up to you.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#i1006566

A primary key itself is not an index, and nor is a unique constraint -- they are both constraints. However an index is used to support them.

A unique index is rather different as it can exist in the absence of a unique or primary key constraint, and neither constraint type require that the index supporting it be unique.

Comment: Hi, I'd just like to ask a followup question. If a primary key has multiple columns, will an index be created for each column or just the combination of all columns? For example if I have primary key(custno, orderno, date) and I want to index 'orderno', do I need to create a secondary index on just orderno or does it already have one created by Oracle because it's part of the primary key?

I tried searching this but couldn't find a clear answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Rash8151 a single index is automatically created for those columns.